# Summarize & Group By with Lodash

Tags: javascript, highcharts, lodash

I'm new to Lodash and I'm trying to perform a complex sum with group by as SQL but I don't find any solution. I have tried to use/combine multiple Lodash functions without success.

My requirement is like this. I have a JSON response:

```
input = 
[{"quantity":1067,"gross_revenue":4094.2,"date":"03","company":"Cat1","product":"Car"},
{"quantity":106,"gross_revenue":409,"date":"02","company":"Cat2","product":"Car"},
{"quantity":106,"gross_revenue":85,"date":"03","company":"Cat2","product":"House"},
{"quantity":106,"gross_revenue":100,"date":"02","company":"Cat3","product":"House"},
{"quantity":20,"gross_revenue":150,"date":"03","company":"Cat5","product":"Technology"},
{"quantity":40,"gross_revenue":100,"date":"01","company":"Cat5","product":"Technology"},
{"quantity":20,"gross_revenue":15,"date":"01","company":"Cat5","product":"Car"},
{"quantity":20,"gross_revenue":18,"date":"01","company":"Cat5","product":"House"},
{"quantity":20,"gross_revenue":2,"date":"01","company":"Cat2","product":"House"},
{"quantity":20,"gross_revenue":25,"date":"01","company":"Cat3","product":"House"}]
```

I need to generate a result as below to populate the series for a HighChart:

```
[{ name: 'Car', data: [15, 409, 4094.2] },
{ name: 'House', data:[45, 100, 85] },
{ name: 'Techonology', data:[100, null, 150] }]
```

Those values are the result from:

1. Make a group by using Product with the tag *name*
2. Based on following procedure, generate an array with the tag *data*

   2.1 Sum the gross revenue based on Product and date (all existing dates)

   2.2 Include a null value if there doesn't exist gross revenue for any existing day

   2.3 Sort the results for gross revenue based on date, ascending order

Is this possible? Or is there another solution for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it - certainly not the only solution...

```js
var input = [
 {"quantity":1067,"gross_revenue":4094.2,"date":"03","company":"Cat1","product":"Car"},
 {"quantity":106,"gross_revenue":409,"date":"02","company":"Cat2","product":"Car"},
 {"quantity":106,"gross_revenue":85,"date":"03","company":"Cat2","product":"House"},
 {"quantity":106,"gross_revenue":100,"date":"02","company":"Cat3","product":"House"},
 {"quantity":20,"gross_revenue":150,"date":"03","company":"Cat5","product":"Technology"},
 {"quantity":40,"gross_revenue":100,"date":"01","company":"Cat5","product":"Technology"},
 {"quantity":20,"gross_revenue":15,"date":"01","company":"Cat5","product":"Car"},
 {"quantity":20,"gross_revenue":18,"date":"01","company":"Cat5","product":"House"},
 {"quantity":20,"gross_revenue":2,"date":"01","company":"Cat2","product":"House"},
 {"quantity":20,"gross_revenue":25,"date":"01","company":"Cat3","product":"House"}
];


var result = [];

var groupedByProduct = _.groupBy(input, "product");

// get the set of unique dates
var dates = _.uniq(_.map(input, 'date'));

// for each product, perform the aggregation
_.forEach(groupedByProduct, function(value, key) {
    // initialize the data array for each date
    data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
        data.push(null);
    }

    // aggregate gross_revenue by date
    _.forEachRight(_.groupBy(groupedByProduct[key], "date"), function(dateValue, dateKey) {
        // use the date as an array index
        data[parseInt(dateKey) - 1] = _.sumBy(dateValue, function(o) {
            return o.gross_revenue
        });
    });
  
    // push into the result array
    result.push({"name": key, "data": data});
});

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.11.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: Excellent @rphv Thanks for your help. It's a combination of solutions as you work with arrays also. I was confused because I was trying to use only Lodash. Now it's clear!

Comment: 2 years later this saved my butt